# How can I improve this post?

Tags: support, specific-question, quality-improvement

I have a question on Stack Overflow that I really want to improve. I want to make it as good as possible, and figured I'd ask for some guideline.

[I'm asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324628/reactjs-for-editing-comments) about [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) and am trying to only include the relevant code to solve the problem.

Here are a few of the things I've already tried:

- Trimming code I believe is not necessary to answer the question. For the [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) code, I removed all declarations of variables and all `app.use` statements. I also removed the `console.error` code.
- Improved the formatting so it's easier to read.
- Added a comment looking for suggestions.
- I've also followed [this style guide](https://github.com/Khan/style-guides/blob/master/style/react.md).

I want to contribute excellent questions and am looking for some tips. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I am a new user and want to become a good one. I'm willing to work hard for it.

Comment: If the code works, and you edit the post to make it appropriate for the format, it may be on-topic on [Codereview.se] (but, please read the CR FAQ first)

Answer (score 31):

You have a lot of code there.  I wouldn't expect most of that to be necessary to reproduce your problem.  Remove as much of it as you can while still having an example that reproduces your problem.

Then with your explanation, remove as much as you can get away with.  If it's not giving me useful information that I would need to create an answer, omit it.  Also make a point of having the most important information, and your main problem statement, as early in the question as possible.  I shouldn't have to read the whole thing to know what your core problem is.  Your problem should be clear from the first few sentences, with the rest just being "the nitty gritty details" that it takes to actually write a full solution.

Comment: @JosephMonroe Some of the principles explained in this answer are outlined on the help page [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And others are explained in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You can find even more details by browsing the various topics at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking